# Facebook's Open Graph Tags for Blogger

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, blogger, share-open-graph

A while ago, some members helped me with Open Graph tags for my Blogger blog. Now I'm trying to add the Facebook versions of the tags - but have no idea now to integrate them with the Twitter tags.

The OG tags I'm currently using are:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2ECL.jpg

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: You haven't explained what you tried. Did you read the Facebook documentation for what tags they need and how did you add them?

Comment: Hiya, to be honest, I haven't tried adding the Facebook tags - I'm a bit concerned that adding them without advise will upset the ones I've already got for Twitter -  https://imgur.com/a/JtE6Vcr

Comment: Then do it on a test page

Comment: True, but that won't tell me what Facebook OG tags I can mix with the Twitter ones. And as some tags are basically the same, just with different wording (image & img for example), are you allowed to have multiple versions of the same tag?

Comment: Sure a test page will tell you that. You test things on the test page and you see if Twitter and Facebook understand it.